# Obtain most successful partnerships in SQL, perhaps using conditional SUMs?

Tags: sql

I have a large datatable that's created from team captains entering data into a spreadsheet, it's basically a scoresheet for our local badminton league. Each match is represented, and all the data for that match contained in that row. e.g. date, division, home team, away team, players, partnerships, scores, etc.

What i'm trying to get out of my data is the most successful partnerships. I've already started by identifying all the different partnerships, by using the following:

```
(SELECT "home mens 1" AS "mens" FROM "Results") UNION
(SELECT "home mens 2" AS "mens" FROM "Results") UNION
(SELECT "home mens 3" AS "mens" FROM "Results") UNION
(SELECT "away mens 1" AS "mens" FROM "Results") UNION
(SELECT "away mens 2" AS "mens" FROM "Results") UNION
(SELECT "away mens 3" AS "mens" FROM "Results") ORDER BY "mens"
```

which gave me a nice list of pairings. You can see the datatable here, with the column headings: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AkFtD3i39wUZdFJSbVVXUUVvNi0wSXNmNEJ5XzhCWEE&output=html

If it's not possible, or if I should restructure the data somehow then I'd love to hear alternative solutions.

I've tried:

```
(SELECT "home mens 1" AS "mens", SUM("home score game 1" + "home score game 2") AS "points total" FROM "Results") UNION
(SELECT "home mens 2" AS "mens", SUM("home score game 5" + "home score game 6") AS     "points total" FROM "Results") UNION
(SELECT "home mens 3" AS "mens", SUM("home score game 9" + "home score game 10") AS "points total" FROM "Results") UNION
(SELECT "away mens 1" AS "mens", SUM("away score game 1" + "away score game 2") AS "points total" FROM "Results") UNION
(SELECT "away mens 2" AS "mens", SUM("away score game 5" + "away score game 6") AS "points total" FROM "Results") UNION
(SELECT "away mens 3" AS "mens", SUM("away score game 9" + "away score game 10") AS "points total" FROM "Results") ORDER BY "mens"`
```

but doesn't seem to work at all..

In terms of relationship between partnerships and game scores: the score columns related to pairs as follows:

- mens pairs 1 play games 1 and 2
- ladies pairs 1 play games 3 and 4
- mens pairs 2 play games 5 & 6
- ladies pairs 2 play games 7 & 8
- mens pairs 3 play games 9 & 10
- ladies pairs 3 play games 11 & 12
- mixed pairs 1 play games 13 & 14
- mixed pairs play games 15 & 16
- mixed pairs 3 play games 17 & 18.

The most successful pair would be the pair that had won the greatest number of games (a score of 15) and then highest number of average points per game.

I'm doing this in OpenOffice Base, I'm not sure what that's based on though in terms of SQL - apparently that means it's using HSQL: http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=140063

Comment: Your question is a little confusing to understand.  What do you mean by the most successful partnerships?  Perhaps desired results would help.

Comment: What RDBMS you are using, Oracle?

Comment: may be it is time to [normalize](http://www.troubleshooters.com/littstip/ltnorm.html) this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you data has something missed, which causes you can NOT find out "the most successful partnerships" accurately. You have all the partnership, all the game score, but there is no relationship between which partnership get which game score and how many score. Or else, it is not hard to find out what you want.

**One Example of how to find the most successful home team partnership**
Note: Assumption RDBMS is Oracle, untested code

```
SELECT A.Partner, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN "GameScore" = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "NumberOfWin", 
       AVG("GameScore") as "AvgGameScore"
FROM (
SELECT "home mens 1" AS "Partner", "home score game 1"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home mens 1" AS "Partner", "home score game 2"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home ladies 1" AS "Partner", "home score game 3"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home ladies 1" AS "Partner", "home score game 4"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home mens 2" AS "Partner", "home score game 5"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home mens 2" AS "Partner", "home score game 6"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home ladies 2" AS "Partner", "home score game 7"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home ladies 2" AS "Partner", "home score game 8"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home mens 3" AS "Partner", "home score game 9"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home mens 3" AS "Partner", "home score game 10"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home ladies 3" AS "Partner", "home score game 11"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home ladies 3" AS "Partner", "home score game 12"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home mixed 1" AS "Partner", "home score game 13"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home mixed 1" AS "Partner", "home score game 14"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home mixed 2" AS "Partner", "home score game 15"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home mixed 2" AS "Partner", "home score game 16"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home mixed 3" AS "Partner", "home score game 17"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  UNION ALL
SELECT "home mixed 3" AS "Partner", "home score game 18"  AS  "GameScore" FROM "Results"  
) A
GROUP BY A.Partner
ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN "GameScore" = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), AVG("GameScore")
```

Comment: aaah, that would help you guys wouldn't it. so, basically the score columns related to pairs as follows, mens pairs 1 play games 1 and 2, ladies pairs 1 play games 3 and 4, mens pairs 2 play games 5 & 6, ladies pairs 2 play games 7 & 8, mens pairs 3 play games 9 & 10, ladies pairs 3 play games 11 & 12, mixed pairs 1 play games 13 & 14, mixed pairs play games 15 & 16, mixed pairs 3 play games 17 & 18. most successful pair would be the pair that had won the greatest number of games (a score of 15) and then highest number of average points per game.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using, SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: tried plugging this in, but get an error i'm afraid. but without any real indication of where the error might be.

Comment: What is the error information, btw, are you using Oracle? which version?

Comment: i'm doing this in OpenOffice Base, i'm not sure what thats based on though in terms of SQL - Apparently that means it's using HSQL http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=140063

Comment: @Big: if you say you get an error but don't say what that error is, people will generally downvote. Please add the error to your question `:)`

Comment: @ljh, halfer: Sorry guys, i didn't have access to the error when i posted yesterday. there are three, although they're not very informative - i've not got enough reputation to post a screengrab of them. SQL status:HY000, Error code:1000. the three error messages are: Syntax error in SQL expression, blank, sytax error, unexpected $end, expecting BETWEEN or IN or SQL_TOKEN_LIKE

Comment: You should have mentioned you were using HSQL when you asked this question. I assumed you used PLSQL. I updated the query, please try again. I'm not familiar with HSQL, I updated query just by limited knowledge.

Comment: @Big: thanks for the error update. Again, if it is related to something in your question, edit it into your question please, so new readers don't have to read all comments on all questions to discover its current status.

Comment: @ljh Almost there.. new error is: SQL Status:37000, Error code:-15, message: 'The data content could not be loaded', Set Function on non-numeric data is not allowed in statement , followed by the SQL you gave me

Comment: @ljh - aaah, no worries, i figured out the cause of the latest error, it's because the score columns were stored as VARCHAR rather than integer, once i'd changed that the query worked :) Thank you so so much, I think i should be able to extend this to include the away pairs, and then break it down into mens, ladies and mixed pairs :) your a legend, thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the contents of a column is what you mean by a "partnership", then you are on the right track.  You need to aggregate, count, and sort from the query you have specified.  Also, you want to use `union all` rather than `union`, because `union` removes duplicates -- which is what you want to find:

```
select "mens", count(*) as cnt
from ((SELECT "home mens 1" AS "mens" FROM "Results") UNION all
      (SELECT "home mens 2" AS "mens" FROM "Results") UNION all
      (SELECT "home mens 3" AS "mens" FROM "Results") UNION all
      (SELECT "away mens 1" AS "mens" FROM "Results") UNION all
      (SELECT "away mens 2" AS "mens" FROM "Results") UNION all
      (SELECT "away mens 3" AS "mens" FROM "Results")
     ) t
group by "mens"
order by count(*) desc
```

This is perhaps just a start.  You'll need to deal with spelling differences and the definition of success might be different.